# xcode can't link UIButton to action

Tags: xcode, button, subview

Learning Xcode and making a simple app.   A "contact" button takes to a subview.    Here buttons for Phone, email, UrL for a website.

Storyboard and assistant editor are side by side.

If button is on the first main controller no problem.

But on  the subview it wont let me connect a button to a method.

Not sure if there is a simple answer to this.

thanks

Comment: where did you declare your "`IBAction`"?

Comment: Check that the view controller you are trying to connect the action to in code has that that file as its class. So if you have a View controller and want to attach it to a action in InfoViewController, make sure your view controller in Storyboard has InfoViewController as its class.

Comment: I have in .h   -(IBAaction)phone;           in .m I have-(IBAction)phone{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:4036575498"]];
}

Comment: Thanks oscar,    I understand what you are saying.  I will try to implement it.